# How should I add a tooltip to an ExtJS Component?

Tags: extjs, tooltip

I'm making an ExtJS Component, and I want it to use a QuickTips tooltip.  If I make an element using DomHelper, I can set a tooltip, no sweat.  If, however, I make a Component, like

```
new BoxComponent({
  qtip: "This is a tip"
});
```

nothing happens.  I've also tried naming the property "tooltip", but no luck.  Is there a right way to do this?  The hack I have in place now that works is

```
new BoxComponent({
  qtip: "This is a tip",
  listeners: {
    rendered: function(c){
      Ext.QuickTips.register({
        target: c.getEl(),
        text: c.qtip
      }
    }
});
```

I feel like that *can't* be right.  I guess I could just extend Component to do that automatically, but it seems like a common enough case that I should be able to do it without poking under the hood like this.

Comment: Note that the event is called 'afterrender', not 'rendered'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're doing it absolutely right. I really don't see the need for QuickTips in arbitrary Components, particularly in Containers, since that might lead to multiple tooltips within the same Component.

Comment: OK, I'm new at all this.  I *just barely* understand the difference between "components" and "elements" (a Component *has an* Element, right?).  What I want to do is, make a *thing on my page* that has a) a tooltip, and b) a click handler.  I'd like to be able to do that with about two lines of code -- am I unreasonable?

Comment: A Component is what other frameworks call a Widget, and consists of nested Elements (which are basically wrappers for DOM nodes). If you need Components with tooltips frequently, you may want to consider creating a plugin, so you could quite simply use `plugins: [ComponentQickTipPlugin], qtip: "This is a tip"` - that's two lines ;)

Comment: It sounds like, unfortunately, the short version is "yes, this should be easier, and no, it isn't." :(

Comment: so i have to add 8 lines of code for each tooltip on my components?

Comment: @OliverWatkins Yep :/ Or override Ext.component with your customized version that includes support for tooltips.

Answer (score 23):

In ExtJS 4.2.1, I am able to add a tip to a checkbox this way:

```
new Ext.form.field.Checkbox({
  ...
  tip: 'This is a tip',
  listeners: {
    render: function(c) {
      Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
        target: c.getEl(),
        html: c.tip 
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

It should work :

```
new BoxComponent({
 tooltip: new Ext.ToolTip({
        title: 'Example Tooltip title',
            text: 'Example Tooltip text'

    }),
  listeners: {
    rendered: function(c){
      Ext.QuickTips.register({
        target: c.getEl(),
        text: c.qtip
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: This helped me in AEM. 
`CQ.Ext.QuickTips.init(); 
new CQ.Ext.form.Checkbox({
            title:'xyz',
            text:'abc',
            listeners: {
                render: function(c) {
                  CQ.Ext.QuickTips.register({
                    target: c,
                    title: c.title,
                    text: c.text,
                    width: 200,
                    dismissDelay: 10000
                  });
                }
            }
        });
`

Answer (score 2):

Hrm. I took a look at how `Ext.Button` does it, with passing `tooltip` to the configuration calling [`setTooltip`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/source/Button.html#method-Ext.Button-setTooltip) under the hood.

Untested, but I think your best bet is something like:

```
Ext.Component.prototype._onRender = Ext.Component.prototype.onRender;
Ext.override(Ext.Component, {
  onRender: Ext.Component.prototype._onRender.createSequence(function(ct, position) {
    // setTooltip code adapted from Ext.Button, looking at tooltip property
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the best way in Extjs 4:

you should add an afterrender listener, then when yor componenten is already created you can add the tooltip, this way:

```
listeners : {
    afterrender : function(obj) {
        if (this.max != null && this.ave != null && this.min != null) {
            obj.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                        target : obj.getEl().getAttribute("id"),
                        trackMouse : true,
                        renderTo : document.body,
                        html : this.htmlTip,
                        title : this.title
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to set 'data-qtip' attribute on the main element of the component:

```
{
    xtype: 'box',
    autoEl: {
        'data-qtip': "Tooltip text"
    }
}
```

Make sure to enable qtips on application startup:

```
Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use this way in ExtJs 3

```
listeners: {
    render: function(c) {
        Ext.QuickTips.register({
            target: c,
            text: 'Enter \'-1\' for a 1 time only'
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way works perfect! Try it! (Extjs 4.2)

```
var boxComponent = Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
  id: 'id111',
  html: '<img src="js/extjs/resources/cb-theme/images/shared/icon-question.png">',
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  margin: '0 0 0 10'
});

Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();

Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.register({
  target: 'id111',
  title: 'My Tooltip',
  text: 'This tooltip was added in code',
  width: 100,
  dismissDelay: 10000 // Hide after 10 seconds hover
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    xtype: 'checkbox',
    fieldLabel: 'Test Label',
    name: 'data_field',
    autoEl: {
        tag: 'div',
        'data-qtip': 'This is a tip'
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '-'" error while using 'data-qtip' attribute

Answer (score -1):

```
{
    xtype: 'checkbox',
    tip: 'This is a tip',
    listeners: {
        render: function(c) {
            Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                target: c.getEl(),
                html: c.tip
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer