# ExtJS 4: Is there any way to attach a QuickTip to a form field?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to add a QuickTip to a form field, but can't find a way to make my code work. Firstly, I tried to use a `qtip` attribute

```
    {
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
        qtip:'This tip is not showing at all',
        name: 'last'
    }
```

and then using `Ext.tip.ToolTip` class:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
    target: 'rating_field',
    anchor: 'right',
    trackMouse: true,
    html: 'This tip is not showing at all'
});

Ext.QuickTips.init();
```

Here is a jsfiddle with the source code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vero4ka/hWGYE/2273/)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes,  use the inputAttrTpl config and the data-qtip attribute:

```
{
    fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
    inputAttrTpl: " data-qtip='This is my quick tip!' ",
    name: 'last'
}
```

Comment: With this method there's no optical indicator that shows that the form field provides a quick tip. Is there an easy way to add an icon if a quick tip is present?

Comment: I do not believe there is a very easy way, but you could add some CSS to change the field border or something with the appropriate configuration option

Comment: that looks seriously ugly. Why can't they just have "qTip: 'my quicktip'"... meh

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer here: [How should I add a tooltip to an ExtJS Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838646/how-should-i-add-a-tooltip-to-an-extjs-component)

```
    {
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
        qtip: "This is a tip",
        name: 'last',
        listeners: {
            render: function(c) {
                Ext.QuickTips.register({
                    target: c.getEl(),
                    text: c.qtip
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: To clarify.  I'd like to point out that while this works, it's just a roundabout way to do the same thing.  All registering with "Ext.QuickTips.register" does is add the data-qtip attribute to the html.  The only real reason to use this way instead is if you want an easier way to escape html with dynamically created qtips.

Answer (score 4):

Using [vero4ka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18256855/4021086) I wrote a simple plugin which can be used with forms to enable quicktips on child fields.

```
Ext.define('Ext.form.QtipPlugin', {
    extend: 'Ext.AbstractPlugin',

    alias: 'plugin.qtipfields',

    init: function (cmp) {
        this.setCmp(cmp);

        cmp.on('beforerender', function () {

            var fields = cmp.query('field[qtip]');

            for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {

                fields[i].on('render', this.register, this);

            }

        }, this);
    },

    register: function (field) {
        var obj = {
            target: field.id
        };

        if (typeof field.qtip === 'string') {
            obj.text = field.qtip;
        } else if (typeof field.qtip === 'object') {
            // Allow qtip configuration objects.
            // i.e. qtip: { text: 'hi', ... }
            Ext.applyIf(obj, field.qtip);
        }

        Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.register(obj);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For any form field, you can use this:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield', // or anything else
    autoEl: {
        'data-qtip': 'This is working tip!'
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for adding a tip to a radiogroup item.  `{boxLabel: 'Flat Rate', name: 'rate_type', inputValue: 1, autoEl: {'data-qtip': 'One rate regardless of usage.'}},`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the built-in plugin datatip on a form panel.
in form panel (see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.ux.DataTip.html) :

in form config :

```
plugins = [{ptype : 'datatip'}]
```

in field text config :

```
tooltip : "my tooltip text"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating tooltip dynamically then you can use below snippet:

```
txtFieldName.el.set({ "data-qtip": Ext.String.htmlDecode("Some Text") });
```