# ExtJS many data-qtips bug

Tags: extjs6, qtip

FIDDLE: https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/222l
This is a form with custom qtips. There is many qtips on one page.

Scroll down the form and put cursor on [?] (in field label) in the bottom of the page. Quick tip will be shown in the top.

How can i fix this error? My form has many fields with qtips, and it should display correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: You can see the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838646/how-should-i-add-a-tooltip-to-an-extjs-component

Comment: @Sudhakar The problem is not to display the qtip, the problem is in qtip's div "stack" in the top of the page when it was scrolled below first visible area loaded (first part of the page which you can see in browser when page became loaded)

Comment: Mistake.. "stuck" *

Answer (score 0):

This question is not answered. The problem was tracked by Sencha as issue EXTJS-24917. So we have to wait for about one year until Sencha fix it.